# What the consequences if the git direct merge to master branch

Tags: git, github

I was wondering for an accident operation I was directly merged my code to the master branch, but the code and logic are correct.

1. Is there have any influences or consequences of the products in such operation?
2. Since this is my company products does it will influence my colleagues who want to merge next time?

Thanks

Comment: There is no way anyone here can answer this. Go talk to your colleagues.

Comment: Something between total disaster and absolutely nothing, depending on what your deployment pipeline looks like. I advise setting up a [pull request review system](https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-request-reviews/).

Comment: To be specific, if you're allowed to push anything to master, have your repository admin prevent it, set up, as @msanford advices, a pull request system so that code is reviewed before ending up in master. Other than this it all depends on the code, it may be perfectly safe for the product but totally wrong policy-wise, nobody here knows.

Comment: usually, we need code review before merge to master. but for an incident that I merged to master branch directly.

Comment: @user2953788 In our company, for example, we have a _formal review process_ which prevents any single person from merging a feature branch to our main branch without at least two approvals from other developers. The merge button is physically disabled.

Comment: Thanks guys for all the suggestions. there is no consequence since my code does affect the products.  But this is definitely the wrong operation. I will suggest our company to hide the merge button or at least multiple people agreed before it merged.